# Strange UIImageView issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I added a UIImageView to my View Controller's main view using interface builder.
Then I just set the image of the UIImageView in the properties.
When I run the app I can't see the image. What can be wrong? Thanks

PS. On the XIB file, if I select the image, I can see it - once I remove focus
from it, it seems like it went to the "back" of the main view (because it is still there, I can see it in the "Objects" window of the XIB file).

pps. It works if I use a different image. Could it be that it was because previous image was with transparent background? (although it still had some icon).

Comment: Could you make sure, that the image is copied during the build phase?

Comment: Make sure that your image view is not hidden.

Comment: Yes I can see it in the Copy bundle resources Tab. @Ankit: No  it is not hidden. It is strange, once I drop a UIImageView on my main view -- all is ok. As soon as I set a image to it from properties, and remove focus from the UIImageView, it is like sent to the back of the main view.

Comment: Mhm thats bad, could you please post a screenshot, maybe there is something to see ....

Comment: This: http://postimg.org/image/4n4x1gkpz/ is how it looks like when I set the image in the properties. And this: http://postimg.org/image/rjsjl2a0f/ is how it looks like when I click the mouse on some different area after the image is set.

Comment: It's probably with the kind of the image (white & light color).Try to give a background colour to your view(superView of UIImageView), you would understand...

Comment: Yes, I will look at it. Because it works with other images, so it must be smth like that.

Comment: It's weird, try to clean your xcode and restart it or you know simply write some code and use [self.view addsubview:yourimage]; , if there is still same result than probably this image has problem with colors as Dinakar said.